# C# WPF editable Combobox how to detect Enter key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I use C# and WPF and MVVM

I have an editable Combobox so that a user can not only select items from the list but also type own text in the comboxbox' textfield

**XAML:**

```xml
<br>
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"<br>
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True" <br>
          IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"<br>
          StaysOpenOnEdit="True"<br>
          Text="{Binding TextEntered}"<br>
</ComboBox>
<br>
```

In the bound property "TextEntered" I can see in the Debugger the text that the user has typed - however this does not work if the user presses ENTER to finished his input.
So how could I react when the users presses Enter ?

thank you

Comment: an alternative is to responding to enter is to do: <ComboBox Text="{Binding StringFormat,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></ComboBox>

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to react on PropertyChanged, you can set the UpdateSourceTrigger to **Explicit**

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
        IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
        IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"
        StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
        Text="{Binding TextEntered, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}">
        <ComboBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Gesture="Enter"
                        Command="{Binding UpdateBindingOnEnterCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}"></KeyBinding>
        </ComboBox.InputBindings>
```

And call **UpdateSource** of the binding in the execute of your command

```
public class UpdateBindingOnEnterCommand : ICommand
{
...
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter is ComboBox control)
        {
            var prop = ComboBox.TextProperty;
            var binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(control, prop);
            binding?.UpdateSource();
        }
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event, for example using an attached behaviour:

```
public class EnterBehavior
{
    public static ICommand GetCommand(UIElement element)
    {
        return (ICommand)element.GetValue(CommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCommand(UIElement element, ICommand value)
    {
        element.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Command",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(EnterBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(OnCommandChanged));


    private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement element = (UIElement)d;

        element.PreviewKeyDown += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            if (ee.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                GetCommand(element)?.Execute(null);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
          local:EnterBehavior.Command="{Binding YourCommandProperty}" ... />
```